# Download translation from launchpad and compile it to use it in application

Tags: translation

I can download translations (.po and .mo) from launchpad. I want to use a translation for [GWoffice](https://translations.launchpad.net/gwoffice) and I don't want to wait when the translation will be released via the official way. How can I compile a translation into the current installation of the app?

Answer (score 2):

`msgfmt -o lang.mo lang.po` should do the work. Then you just need to replace current translation. `dpkg -L gwoffice | grep "\.mo$"` should help you locate needed files.